# Rails how to switch between dev and production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I switch in Rails between the dev mode and the production mode?

and how can I deploy the database to production?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you are using Rails 4.2 then you must know rails uses "spring" to make it faster. So in that case you can use following commands:

For Development just run

```
Rails 4.2
    bin\rails s
Otherwise
   rails s
```

For Production just run

```
Rails 4.2
    bin\rails s -e production
Otherwise    
    rails s -e production
```

To setup production database
if database in production does not exist then run

```
Rails 4.2
    bin/rake db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
Otherwise
    rake db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
    bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

If DB already exists the:

```
Rails 4.2
  bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
Otherwise
  rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
  OR
  bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Also if you want to stop spring or start spring then use following commands:

```
 bin/spring stop
 bin/spring start
```

Answer (score 22):

Start server using `-e` option.

```
rails server -e production
```

And you can not deploy database. you needs migrations to run in production.

Comment: `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate` maybe you will not have created database so you will have to run `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create` and `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:schema:load` and your production database will be set up.

Comment: rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV="production"

Comment: in Rails 6 make sure `config.public_file_server.enabled = true` if using `puma` locally.

Answer (score 6):

To start your server in development mode you only need to run `rails s` it will start your app in dev mode as well as your database.

To start your server in production mode you need to migrate your database with `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` and then start your server in production using `rails s -e production` or `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`

Comment: rake db:setup RAILS_ENV=production worked for me ... 

but now I have the problem that no styles etc were loaded .. :(

Comment: That may be an assets issue which is different from this question. Try to google it, there are plenty of questions/answers for this kind of issue

Comment: @Felix try `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

Answer (score 5):

In rails 5+
goto

```
config/puma.rb
```

You can find the below line

```
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
```

change "development" to "production"

Comment: "development" here is the default value when RAILS_ENV environment variable is missing. So, this answer is not exactly right - it's better to set RAILS_ENV environment variable to "production" than change the default value here.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to run the server in production and enable the logs in the console you can run:

```
rails s -C --log-to-stdout -e production
```