# How do I turn off error details in Unicorn?

Tags: ruby, unicorn

I'm using Ruby and Unicorn for developing my web pages. When there's an error in my page Unicorn displays a page detailing the error and the lines in my code where the error occurs. That's fine for development, but I don't want so much detail in the public web page. I know there's a way to turn off all that detail but darned if I can remember it for find the info online.

So, how do I turn off all that detail?

Comment: Are your sure that error messages are still visible in production mode? As far as I know, default Server Error Page will be shown in production mode by default.

Comment: I don't know what production mode is, so that's probably the problem. I do know that the errors are being displayed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30119144/rails-how-to-switch-between-dev-and-production-mode - this will help, In short, you should run your server in development mode (it is default) on dev machines and production mode on the real life server. Production mode will hide error messages.